# What's the probability that all the white balls are placed in the same box?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $6n$ balls.  Among them there are $n$ indistinguishable white balls and $5n$ indistinguishable black balls. I want to randomly divide them into $2$ boxes so that each box has $3n$ balls. What's the probability that all the white balls are placed in the same box?

I somehow struggle with the requirement of evenly distributing them. To put all $n$ white balls in the same box is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. But how do I enforce the constraint of evenly distributed?

Comment: there are $3n$ balls in each box. If balls were all distinct, number of ways of having all white balls in a given box is  ${5n \choose 3n}$ so the probability is $2 \cdot {5n \choose 3n} / {6n \choose 3n}$

Comment: What @MathLover is saying is that if all the white balls are placed in one of the boxes, then $3n$ of the $5n$ black balls must be placed in the other box.

Comment: @MathLover Why is there a 2 in front?

Comment: Because all the white balls could be in either box.